# Adding terminal commands into crontab

Tags: cron

I have this terminal command `show_space`, when run, it will displays some stats such as how much disk space is used and left (in percentages, sizes etc) in my drive.

As I tried to put this command into a crontab as follows:

```
0   20  *   10  * show_space
```

I got the following error:

```
/bin/sh: show_space: command not found
```

Is it possible to integrate terminal based commands into crontab?

Comment: what os you are using?

Comment: Linux is the os I am using

Comment: how did you installed the command? or its some shell script you wrote?

Comment: Looks like bash can't find the command, may be you need to give full path of the command in the cronjob.

Comment: @geek This time round, I tried to give it the full path, however while it is being executed in the crontab, this time round, it is stating that it is stating `ImportError` of the modules..

Comment: Strange, what is the full error message you are seeing? Is that a python script?